# AudioPlayers package (Flutter) showing Incompaitble classes were found in dependencies. I attached the whole main.dart and pubspec.yaml file below

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

The below code is main.dart. Its actually code from the udemy course but updated to flutter 2.2.2.
I want to just play the sound when the TextButton is tapped. There are 7 sounds of .wav format. I hope .wav is supported by this package. I also test it with .mp3 format but it doesnot work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(XylophoneApp());
}

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void playSound(int soundNumber) {
    final player = AudioCache();
    player.play('note$soundNumber.wav');
  }

  Expanded buildKey({required Color color, required int soundNumber}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: TextButton(
        child: Text("Hello"),
        onPressed: () {
          playSound(soundNumber);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                buildKey(color: Colors.red, soundNumber: 1),
                buildKey(color: Colors.orange, soundNumber: 2),
                buildKey(color: Colors.yellow, soundNumber: 3),
                buildKey(color: Colors.green, soundNumber: 4),
                buildKey(color: Colors.teal, soundNumber: 5),
                buildKey(color: Colors.blue, soundNumber: 6),
                buildKey(color: Colors.purple, soundNumber: 7),
              ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and for pubspec.yaml file I only added the audioplayers package in dependencies.

```
name: xylophone1
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  audioplayers: ^0.19.1
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Do help. Why this code not working?

The error snippets:
[image]

[image]

The error is as long as a 10 pages book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**audioplayers 0.19.1**

1. edit `android\build.gradle` in the project.
2. changed `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'` to `ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'`

I thinks this is a package specific issue

Comment: App ran but with 'Parameter format not correct' is still there. Any solution for that.

Comment: this happens every time you run a project build by the previous version of flutter... and this error is not a big deal... dont worry...